# How to allow security parameter (apiKey) to take empty or null values in Swagger 2.0

Tags: authentication, go, swagger, swagger-2.0

I want my swagger code to allow empty or nil user_id.
I want to achieve this:

```
Receive a token, no user_id: Success
Receive a token, receive user_id: Success
No token, receive user_id: Failure
No token, no user_id: Failure
```

Here is my Security Definitions in swagger file:

```
securityDefinitions:
  BearerToken:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: authorization
  UserId:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: user_id
```

Here is what I use in my API:

```
security:
 - BearerToken: []
   UserId: []
 - ServiceAPIKey: []
```

I am using logical AND and OR in my `security` to achieve my goal. But I am failing when the `user_id` is `empty/nil`.

Here is what I have achieved so far:

```
Receive a token, no user_id: Failing (I need this to succeed)
Receive a token, receive user_id: Done
No token, receive user_id: Done
No token, no user_id: Done
```

I tried using logical AND and OR in my `security` but it is failing when the `user_id` is `empty/nil`. I also tried adding extra `token` in `security`, like this:

```
security:
 - BearerToken: []
   UserId: []
 - ServiceAPIKey: []
 - BearerToken: []
```

but that is also not working.

BTW, here is my code in the handlers level:

```
// service auth handler
    handler.BearerTokenAuth = func(token string) (interface{}, error) {
        authToken = token
        authPrincipal, err := rt.Client().AuthenticateRequest(token, http.MethodGet, "", "")
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New(401, "invalid bearer token")
        }

        return authPrincipal, nil
    }

// service auth handler
    handler.UserIDAuth = func(userId string) (interface{}, error) {
        authPrincipal, err := rt.Client().AuthenticateRequest(authToken, http.MethodGet, "", userId)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.New(401, "invalid user id")
        }

        return authPrincipal, nil
    }
```